# how to set action attribute of the html:form according to javascript conditions written below

Tags: javascript

```
 function setReqcode(id,methodName){

    if(document.getElementById('approve').value==id)
    {
        alert("inside approve"+methodName);
        action="ProcessPath.do?reqCode=approveVersion";
    }

    if(document.getElementById('reject').value==id)
    {
        alert("inside reject"+methodName);
        action="ProcessPath.do?reqCode=rejectVersion"
    }
}
```

i have to change the html:form action attribute according to if condition.
so please suggest some solution with example.

Answer (score 0):

```
formReference.setAttribute('action', 'blah')
```

or

```
formRef.action='foo'
```

should suffice.

Comment: please suggest me with help of an example